# CSS Transition not working properly

Tags: html, css

I have the following code: http://jsfiddle.net/8TG8L/

On another part of my HTML I can get the transition CSS to work great, but here on the right hand side I cannot get the transition to have any delay.

Relevant code:

```
.home_subvid_hover {
    background-image:url('http://www.ptroa.com/images/video_hover.png');    
    /*background-repeat:no-repeat;*/
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

**EDIT**:

To clarify, please look at this code: http://jsfiddle.net/9UuY7/

That one works although it's the same principle as the first one, why is that?
Thanks,

Comment: I didn't understand your problem.

Comment: What do you expect it to do?  Last [I read](http://blog.alexmaccaw.com/css-transitions), `background-image` transition was not generally supported.

Comment: @harpo please see my last edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the background isn't animated, is because the `backround-image` isn't set on the initial class `.home_subvid`.

You can't animate `background-image:none` to `background-image:url(...)`.

If you try this, it's gonna work:

```
.home_subvid {   
    background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1x1/000');    
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out; 
}
.home_subvid:hover {
    background-image:url('http://www.ptroa.com/images/video_hover.png');    
    /*background-repeat:no-repeat;*/
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8TG8L/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Your css is changing the background image from *nothing* to *an image*, which the current generation of CSS can't animate.

Comment: Of course it can be animated, I'm doing the same for the top menu (not included in the code I uploaded) and it works perfectly

Comment: Your edit shows that normally the nav button has a *different* `background-image`. In your original example, your default div has *no* `background-image`.  Try adding a blank image at the same size as your hover image and see if that works.

Comment: @Scrimothy I'll try that, any idea why does this happen?

Comment: I'm not sure why it works aside from that the browser doesn't know how to go from nothing to image and back to nothing. It can transition from image to image, but not to nothing. (Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scrimothy/8TG8L/2/)--works in webkit, not in moz)

Comment: Thanks @Scrimothy, that's a more correct way to explain what's happening.  I'll update my answer in case anyone else runs across this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't transition background images from `none` to an image, [see this document on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties). Transitioning from image to image doesn't have amazing browser support either; as far as I know it's only supported in Chrome.

You can, however, create a similar effect with different markup/CSS.

How about an element made invisible with `opacity: 0;` and then transitioned into `opacity: 1;` when hovered?